# How to save ms-office document In other document server using URI scheme

Tags: javascript, java, ms-office, url-scheme

I want to save document which document(From my cloud-based product) opened in Microsoft office(Ms-office Application).

I have used [URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes) for direct document open view/edit mode in Ms-office Application which installed in your system(Windows/MAC) using javascript.

i have use below code for edit any ms-office document format.

```
 "ms-excel:ofe|u|http://serverip:port/filepath"
```

after edit document and done all modifications how to save modified document in my product server?

Is there any suggestions? Please help.

Comment: Any other way to Edit documents?